# How to reload all tabs at a particular time each day in a Chrome extension

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am trying to write a Chrome extension that can reload all Google Chrome tabs at 7AM. I have to do this every day and it will be nice to have a small program that does it for me. I have tried one of the existing extensions but it's not working correctly for me, so I've taken some existing code and am trying to make it do what I want:

```
219     updateMonitorSelectors: function () {
220         //p.ex.currentReload.monitor.selectors.length = 0;
221         if (p.v.isInitSelector) return;
222         p.ex.currentReload.monitor.selectors = [];
223         $(p.s.dMonitor_nu + ' input[type="text"]').each(function () {
224             var disabled = $(this).attr('disabled');
225             if (!disabled) {
226                 p.ex.currentReload.monitor.selectors[p.ex.currentReload.moni    tor.selectors.length] = $(this).val();
227             }
228         });
229     },
230     initControls: function () {
231         if (this.initControls.timerId) clearTimeout(this.initControls.timerI    d);
232         if (p.ex.currentReload === null) { this.initControls.timerId = setTi    meout('p.initControls()', 250); return; };
233         var reload = p.ex.currentReload;
234         $(p.s.tRandomStartSecs).val(reload.rand.from);
235         $(p.s.tRandomEndMins).val(reload.rand.to / 60);
236         $(p.s.tCustomSecs).val(reload.secs);
237         $(p.s.tDefaultSecs).val(p.ex.defaultTime);
238         if (reload.isTabRefresh) { $(p.s.rTab).attr('checked', 'checked'); }
239         else $(p.s.rUrl).attr('checked', 'checked');
240
241         if (reload.span.isStartOn) {
242             $(p.s.cStart).attr('checked', 'checked');
243             $(p.s.tStart).removeAttr('disabled');
244             $(p.s.tStart).val(p.time.toLocal(reload.span.startTime));
245         }
246         if (reload.span.isEndOn) {
247             $(p.s.cEnd).attr('checked', 'checked');
248             $(p.s.tEnd).removeAttr('disabled');
249             $(p.s.tEnd).val(p.time.toLocal(reload.span.endTime));
250         }
251
```

Comment: There are Chrome extensions that do this already. For example, [Refresh Monkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/refresh-monkey/ljngnafhejmefmijjoedbclkadhacebd). It doesn't have a feature to do it at an exact time, but you can say "Between 7am and 7:01am refresh once a minute" to get the same effect.

Comment: @WarrenYoung - yes but this will only happened once a day i.e 13 - 14th May then i have to reset the date to 15th and 16th. it won't do it automatically everyday.

Comment: So take one of those scripts and adjust it to suit.

Comment: @WarrenYoung these are only plugins i don't think i can edit their script. If your talking about online script suggested by people I've tried (the one mentioned in question) but it doesn't work. Fell free to post some links so I can try them.

Comment: @WarrenYoung - I've found the code that shows date. But my programming knowledge is basic. I've posted updated code can you/someone help me edit this?